# How to select childs in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists

I'have a nav list and wanted to place an icon in front of nav item, so I'm doing this way but it's putting the same icon on all nav item.

How can I select 1,2,3 and 4 nav item and put different nav icon for each one in CSS ?

It's not working, still it's showing the first icon for all, not changing for 2,3 and 4.

```css
.shop-menu .mobile-nav__link:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height:100%;
  background: url("/files/NewArrivalsIcon.png?v=1635225557") no-repeat center center transparent;
  background-size: contain;
}
.shop-menu .mobile-nav__link:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height:100%;
  

background: url("files/AnimalPrintsIcon.png?v=1635225557") no-repeat center center transparent;
  background-size: contain;
}
.shop-menu .mobile-nav__link:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height:100%;
  background: url("files/Under500Icon.png?v=1635225557") no-repeat center center transparent;
  background-size: contain;
}
.shop-menu .mobile-nav__link:nth-child(4)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height:100%;
  background: url("files/NewArrivalsIcon.png?v=1635225557") no-repeat center center transparent;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML structure we can only guess. Please put it in your question. For what it's worth my guess is that your items are all the first-child of their respective parents so you are getting the first img each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set unique IDs for each nav item, here is an example.

```css
#item1::before {
content:'1'
}

#item2::before {
content:'2'
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="item1"></li>
  <li id="item2"></li>
</ul>
```

**Solution #2**

You can also use the nth-child selector.

However, keep in mind that the 'order' depends on the overall order including all elements. So for example if you have a div containing 2 img elements and 1 p element in this order:

```
<div>
   <p>
   <img>
   <img>
</div>
```

Then to select the last image, you would use nth-child(3) (not 2 for 2nd image).

Comment: Why not put both answer into the same answer?

Comment: Is it best practice to do so? I was unsure.

Comment: I would say yes in general.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a correct answer, a look at your HTML code would be nice.
You can select specific children by using the :nth selector.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li:nth-child(1):before {
    content: '1';
}
li:nth-child(2):before {
    content: '2';
}
li:nth-child(3):before {
    content: '3';
}
li:nth-child(4):before {
    content: '4';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
```